# Solve $A^2=B$ where $B$ is the $3\times3$ matrix whose only nonzero entry is the top right entry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all the matrices $A$ such that  $$A^2= \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end {array} \right) $$  where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix.

$A= \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&1&1\\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0\end {array} \right) $
 and 
$A= \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0\end {array} \right) $ work,

but how can I find all the matrices?

Comment: Calculate $A^2$ for matrix with unknown entries, and extract 9 equations to solve.

Comment: Is there any easier way than  9 equations to solve?

Comment: Perhaps solve in terms of Jordan normal forms?

Comment: Think about it this way. You want the dot product of any column and any row to be zero except for the top row and last column.

Comment: @did Why is 3x3 in titles bad ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Too much vertical space taken in the list of questions, for no reason. (Hmmm, my first comment seems to have disappeared. Yet another misdeed of the fake congenial mentality some try to impose on the site, I guess. This way, the OP shall feel authorized to post other similarly terribly formatted posts...  Well done.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $A^4=0$, and since it is a $3\times 3$ matrix it follows that $A^3=0$. This means that 
$$A\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}=0$$
and 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}A=0$$

Giving that

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&a&b\\
0&c&d\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Now we have

$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&ac&ad\\
0&c^2&dc\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
 So $c=0$ and $ad=1$. Thus the general solution is

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&a&b\\
0&0&a^{-1}\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @J.G.The minimal polynomial has degree $\leq 3$.

Comment: @J.G. But the minimal poly divides $A^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A^4=0$. Thus all eigenvalues of $A$ must be $0$ thus its Jordan normal form has one of the following forms
$$
A_1=\left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end {array} \right) \text{ or }  
A_2=\left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end {array} \right)
\text{ or }
A_3=\left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0\end {array} \right)
$$
The first two options are immediately disqualified because their square is $0$. Thus $A$ must be similar $A_3$, i.e. $A= CA_3C^{-1}$ for an invertible C. Now $B = A^2 = C A_3^2 C^{-1} = C B C^{-1}$, thus $B$ and $C$ have to commute. Thus your space of solutions to $A^2 = B$ is given by

$$\{CA_3C^{-1}\vert C \in Gl(\mathbb{R},3), [B,C] = 0\}$$

By solving the linear equation $[B,C] = 0$ you see $C$ satisfies $C \in Gl(\mathbb{R},3), [B,C] = 0$ if and only if it is of the form

$$C=\left( \begin {array}{ccc} \lambda&*&*\\ 0&\mu&* \\ 0&0&\lambda\end {array} \right) $$

for $\lambda,\mu \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about all solutions, but given one solution, you can generate an infinity many other solutions: Let
$$
P=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & y\\
0 & 1 & z \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that 
$$
P^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -x & xz-y\\
0 & 1 & -z \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If 
$$
A^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then 
$$
(P^{-1}AP)^2=P^{-1}A^2P=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -x & xz-y\\
0 & 1 & -z \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & y\\
0 & 1 & z \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: i think that if i take $$A= \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 0&x&z\\ 0&0&y \\ 0&0&0\end {array} \right) $$ then i need just x*y = 1 thats mean x*1/x  and z can be any number